# JFormattedTextField getValue with or without commit depending on different listeners

Tags: java, actionlistener, commit, keylistener

Can someone explain me why these two codes don't give the same result?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame jf = new JFrame("test jftf"); 
    JFormattedTextField jftf = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance()); 
    jftf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(jftf.getValue());
        }

    });
    jf.add(jftf); 
    jf.setSize(100, 100);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    jf.setVisible(true); 
}
```

and

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame jf = new JFrame("test jftf"); 
    JFormattedTextField jftf = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance()); 
    jftf.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println(jftf.getValue());
        }
    });
    jf.add(jftf); 
    jf.setSize(100, 100);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    jf.setVisible(true); 
}
```

The first one works fine, but the second needs a commit statement before using `getValue()`. I think the reason is that these two listeners are implemented differently, but I can't say more since I don't know how they are implemented.

Comment: I don't understand.
In both cases, committing (here enter press key)should be needed  to get the value from the field.
Why do you say that the first works ? Can you detail.

Comment: I say that the first one works because when you test it, the result is correct. But in the second one, the getValue() function returns null. You need to add 'jftf.commitEdit()' to get the result. But I don't understand why do you need to add that statment for a KeyListener and not for an ActionListener.

Comment: In your sample, I don't see commitEdit() used

Comment: That's why the second one returns null :)

Comment: we don't understand each other lol

Comment: The first one doesn't need the commitEdit() statement, but the second does, and I just want to know why ^^